# Facebook integration

Tags: c#, facebook

I'm trying to implement facebook like button & comments in my website & I'm facing issues with comments box in IE7. The COMMENT USING dropdown box is somehow not showing up other options available. Here is the code snippet I'm using to implement it:

```
          <fb:like></fb:like>
          <br />
          <fb:comments href="http://votingapplication/confirmation.aspx" num_posts="2" height="200px" width="500">
          </fb:comments>
```

Comment: I think you are more lickly to get an answer on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/, as there is no code in your question and it is lickly that a lot of the user of webmaster have done this.

Answer (score 0):

The comments plugin is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

To enable other login methods (e.g. Yahoo!) you need to:

- Specify the Facebook user(s) who will administer the plugin:
- Go to the administration interface: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments
- Click settings
- Change the 'Other login providers' option

Answer (score -2):

fb:comments is depreciated by facebook and does not support href according to their sdk - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments_(XFBML)/

I think you need to find another way.

Comment: That link is for the old FBML version, the current version is also included on a page with <fb:comments... and is documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/